# Can I say $\log{O(n)}$?

Tags: terminology, asymptotics

Suppose $e^{f(x)} = O(x)$, or equivalently, there exists a $c$ such that for all $x$, $f(x) \lt \ \log{x} + c$.  Is $f(x) = \log{O(x)}$ generally understood to mean the same thing?

Comment: $\log O(x)=\log x+\log O(1)$ so yes, it means the same thing. What else could it mean?

Comment: @A.S. Just because a notation can only reasonably mean a single thing does not imply it is actually used (and likewise for the converse, but that is a different issue). My favourite example, by analogy of unary minus $-a$ meaning additive inverse (opposite), the only reasonable thing unary division $/a$ could mean is multiplicative inverse (reciprocal). Yet everybody uses the longer $1/a$, and often (group theory, matrices) even that is not done, reverting to the even more convoluted $a^{-1}$ instead (which is analogous to writing $-a$ as $a*(-1)$).

Comment: @Marc Admittedly, I haven't seen $\log O(1)$ used before, but $e^{o(1)}$ is certainly used, so it's not a huge stretch. $/a$ could be a useful shortcut, though $1/a$ is already a "shortcut" for $\frac 1 a$. I don't see $a^{-1}$ as convoluted but appropriate and consistent since $a$ stands for $+a$ and $a$ for $a^{+1}$ so inverses just flip $+$ to $-$ but it does seem to use unnecessary characters.

Answer (score -2):

The standard is to write **O(log n)**.

See also: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2307283/what-does-olog-n-mean-exactly

Comment: Not the same thing. An $O(\ln(n))$ is not necessarily an $\ln( O(n) )$